# Global Date Variable Works Only for Entered Values

Tags: ms-access, parameters, datepicker, global-variables, ms-access-2010

I'm currently working on what should be a relatively simple database, which is very close to being at its end, until I hit the inevitable problem.

I'm using Global Variables and a Form to collect parameters to pass into the Criteria portion of a Query, which works just fine for the first two, which are basic strings and integers.

Then comes the dates, which work, so long as you chose a date from the DatePicker that is entered into the query.

For example, if the query field holds 6/1/2014, 6/3/2014, and 6/8/2014, and the date 6/5/2014 is picked, the form will crash and go blank, though if you pick 6/8/2014, it'll go on as it should.

I had tried a variety of different forms of the code, but in the most basic form I simple have:

`Between Get_Global('GBL_Start_Date_ID') AND Get_Global('GBL_End_Date_ID')`

I'm not sure if I should be limiting the DatePicker based on the values entered in the query, or if there's a more robust way of going about this, or maybe I just completely missed a simple checkbox.

**EDIT**

My code for the Global Variables looks like this:

```
Option Compare Database
Global GBL_Start_Date_ID As Date
Global GBL_End_Date_ID As Date
Global GBL_Customer_ID As Long
Global GBL_Engineer_ID As Long

Public Function Init_Globals()
GBL_Start_Date_ID = #6/1/2014#
GBL_End_Date_ID = #6/30/2014#
GBL_Customer_ID = 1
GBL_Engineer_ID = 1
End Function

Public Function Get_Global(gbl_parm)
Select Case gbl_parm
    Case "GBL_Customer_ID"
        Get_Global = GBL_Customer_ID
    Case "GBL_Engineer_ID"
        Get_Global = GBL_Engineer_ID
    Case "GBL_Start_Date_ID"
        Get_Global = GBL_Start_Date_ID
    Case "GBL_End_Date_ID"
        Get_Global = GBL_End_Date_ID
End Select
End Function
```

And I just add a simple line to the AfterUpdate event of the ComboBoxes and TextBoxes to assign the variable:

```
GBL_Engineer_ID = Me.EngineerSelection
```

Thanks in advance,

Aaron

Comment: Dates should never be encapsulated in `'`  (because it treats it as a string).. `#` are required if you're hard-coding a date in (or using a variable in lieu of a date in VBA). Did you try to run it without the single quotes?

Comment: What is in your `Get_Global` function? I don't think this is a `'`/`#` issue @OverMind. I'm guessing by "Global" OP means they are using `TempVars` which returns null if the item is not found which would cause a syntax error in the `Between` statement. But it's all hard to tell. Need more info.

Comment: @Brad anything is possible at this point haha I just felt the need to throw a little something  out there!

Comment: Thanks guys, I edited in the Get_Global function to the original post, and I tried added the `#` and again with removing the `'`. The `#` showed an error with the date format (mainly because I had a string inside date indicators) and removing the `'` held the same issue as with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things. Fix the query as it is written or make it much more robust.

To fix it as written

```
Between "#" & Get_Global('GBL_Start_Date_ID') & "#" AND "#" & Get_Global('GBL_End_Date_ID') & "#"
```

OR

change your `Get_Global` function

```
Public Function Get_Global(gbl_parm)
    Select Case gbl_parm
        Case "GBL_Customer_ID"
            Get_Global = GBL_Customer_ID
        Case "GBL_Engineer_ID"
            Get_Global = GBL_Engineer_ID
        Case "GBL_Start_Date_ID"
            Get_Global = "#" & GBL_Start_Date_ID & "#"
        Case "GBL_End_Date_ID"
            Get_Global = "#" & GBL_End_Date_ID & "#"
    End Select
End Function
```

You are correctly specifying that the values of `GBL_Start_Date_ID` and `GBL_End_Date_ID` are dates by using `#`s when you create them however when you use them in your query they appear without them. You can prove to yourself this is what is happening by typing `?#1/1/2014#` into the immediate window. The date is printed as `1/1/2014` which when used in your query, makes `Between 6/1/2014 AND 6/30/2014` which is a syntax error.

To make things all that much better you need to parameterize this part of your query. Change this

```
Between Get_Global('GBL_Start_Date_ID') AND Get_Global('GBL_End_Date_ID')
```

to this

```
Between pStartDate AND pEndDate
```

Before you call your query you need to do your usual checks: are either of these null? is `pStartDate` < `pEndDate`?

By performing these checks and parameterizing this you ensure that you never end up with a query like this. Calling your query means you need to need to populate the parameters with DAO or ADO.

```
Between AND
```